# Configure WinRM over HTTPS on Multiple Computers with Powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, foreach, winrm, foreach-object

Configure WinRM over HTTPS on Multiple Computers with Powershell

I have the following script that I put together to configure WinRM over HTTPS and it works great on per machine. I am having a tough time recoding it to run remotely on multiple machines located in a text file.

Also as a bonus, i would like some kind of logging and checking in place for machines that fail or bring back any type of errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

````
$user = "Account to Use - Service Account Suggested"
$Certname = "HOSTNAME FQDN"
$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname $Certname
$pw = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pazzword" -Force -AsPlainText
$thumbprint = $Cert.Thumbprint
WinRM e winrm/config/listener
#winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="$Certname"; CertificateThumbprint=$thumbprint}'
New-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener -Address * -Transport HTTPS -HostName $Certname -CertificateThumbPrint $thumbprint
$port=5986
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTPS-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port
net localgroup "Remote Management Users" /add $user
net localgroup "Event Log Readers" /add $user
Restart-Service WinRM
Restart-Service Winmgmt -Force


#Adding the below script should replace "winrm configSDDL default"
$GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000
$GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000
$GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000
$GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000

# get SID of user/group to add

$user_sid = (New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList $user).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

# get the existing SDDL of the WinRM listener
$sddl = (Get-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL).Value

# convert the SDDL string to a SecurityDescriptor object
$sd = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList $false, $false, $sddl

# apply a new DACL to the SecurityDescriptor object
$sd.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess(
[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow,
$user_sid,
($GENERIC_READ -bor $GENERIC_EXECUTE),
[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None,
[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
)

# get the SDDL string from the changed SecurityDescriptor object
$new_sddl = $sd.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All)

# apply the new SDDL to the WinRM listener
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL -Value $new_sddl -Force```
````

Comment: Use your code as is, in a loop. Passing in a list of computers using the normal PowerShell remoting session., or set it as a logon script via GPO. Logging you'll need to define what that is and write that in. See teh PowerShell help files for logging or the plethora of articles online on that topic.

Comment: how do i pass it in a loop with a list of computers but also put in the computer name in the $certname variable?

Answer (score 0):

A follow-up to our comment exchange.

Assuming this line ...

```
$user       = "Account to Use - Service Account Suggested"
```

... would be the same for all systems, then pre-populate this with whatever that is, then...

> [Get-ADComputer (activedirectory) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-adcomputer?view=winserver2012-ps)
>
> [about_Foreach - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach)

```
(Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Server" -and enabled -eq "True"').Name | 
ForEach {
    $user       = "Account to Use - Service Account Suggested"
    $Certname   = $PSItem
...
}
```

You are already asking for the certname dynamically here...

```
$Cert       = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation 'cert:\localmachine\my' -dnsname $Certname
$pw         = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Pazzword" -Force -AsPlainText
$thumbprint = $Cert.Thumbprint
```

... so nothing to pass in.

Yet, to run this script on a remote target, just use the normal default PSRemoting remote session setup.

> [about_Remote - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote)
>
> [about_Remote_Requirements - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server01 -ScriptBlock {Get-Culture}
```

So, like this...

```
$Creds = Get-Credential -Credential "$env:USERDOMAIN\$env:USERNAME"
(Get-ADComputer -Filter 'OperatingSystem -NotLike "*Server" -and enabled -eq "True"').Name | 
ForEach {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $PSItem -ScriptBlock {
        $user       = "Account to Use - Service Account Suggested"
        $Certname   = $PSItem
        ...
    } -Credential $Creds

}
```

Comment: Im confused on how to convert my script into a for each

Answer (score 0):

The below script gives me the following error

```
CloneCert and DnsName parameters cannot both be empty
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-SelfSignedCertificate], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException,Microsoft.CertificateServices.Commands.NewSelfSignedCertificateCommand
    + PSComputerName        : XXX.local
 
Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 172.17.62.29, ::1, fe80::c5c5:a94f:341c:48fa%13

Cannot validate argument on parameter 'HostName'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [New-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
    + PSComputerName        : XXXX.local
 

An error occurred while attempting to contact the  Windows Firewall service. Make sure that the service is running and try your request again.
```

```html
$Computers = get-content "C:\temp\regkey.txt"
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer -ScriptBlock {

    $user = "bmonitor-ps"
    #$Certname = $Computer
    $Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname $Computer
    $thumbprint = $Cert.Thumbprint


WinRM e winrm/config/listener
#winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS '@{Hostname="$Certname"; CertificateThumbprint=$thumbprint}'
New-Item WSMan:\localhost\Listener -Address * -Transport HTTPS -HostName $Computer -CertificateThumbPrint $thumbprint
$port=5986
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="Windows Remote Management (HTTPS-In)" dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=$port
net localgroup "Remote Management Users" /add $user
net localgroup "Event Log Readers" /add $user
Restart-Service WinRM
Restart-Service Winmgmt -Force


#Adding the below script should replace "winrm configSDDL default"
$GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000
$GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000
$GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000
$GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000

# get SID of user/group to add

$user_sid = (New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Principal.NTAccount -ArgumentList $user).Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])

# get the existing SDDL of the WinRM listener
$sddl = (Get-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL).Value

# convert the SDDL string to a SecurityDescriptor object
$sd = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.CommonSecurityDescriptor -ArgumentList $false, $false, $sddl

# apply a new DACL to the SecurityDescriptor object
$sd.DiscretionaryAcl.AddAccess(
[System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow,
$user_sid,
($GENERIC_READ -bor $GENERIC_EXECUTE),
[System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags]::None,
[System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags]::None
)

# get the SDDL string from the changed SecurityDescriptor object
$new_sddl = $sd.GetSddlForm([System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlSections]::All)

# apply the new SDDL to the WinRM listener
Set-Item -Path WSMan:\localhost\Service\RootSDDL -Value $new_sddl -Force


}
}
```